# Jasmine spyOn NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jasmine, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I was wondering if you can help me.  I am using Jasmine spies with NodeJS.  I am trying to mock a function, which gets called by another function. But the mock does not look like it is working.

**api.js**

```
function hello() {
    greeting();
}

function greeting() {
    console.log("welcome!");
    console.log("But instead it prints this!");
}

module.export = {
    hello    : hello,
    greeting : greeting
}
```

**api-spec.js**

```
const api = require("./api")

describe("testing jasmine spies", function() {
    it("mocks the greeting", function() => {
        spyOn(api, "greeting").and.callFake(function() {
            console.log("it should print this, since I am mocking it...")
        });

        api.hello();
    });
});
```

As you can see, I mock `greeting`, which gets called by `hello`.  So, when I call hello from my spec, I expect it to call the mocked version of my `greeting` function.  But it calls the actual implementation instead.

Can you please help me?

Comment: I'm facing this exact same issue in nodeJS and using `this` on the peer function still does not trigger the `spyOn` mock for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider the difference how to test `this.greeting()` and `greeting()` function call.

#### Executed in global / window scope

```js
function hello() {
  greeting();
}

function greeting() {
  console.log('original greeting')
}

api = {
  hello: hello,
  greeting: greeting
}

describe("jasmine spies on global object", function() {
  it("mocks the window.greeting()", function() {
    spyOn(window, "greeting").and.callFake(function() {
      console.log("stubbed `api.greeting()`")
    });
    api.hello();
    expect(window.greeting).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```

#### Executed in object context

```js
function hello() {
  this.greeting();
}

function greeting() {
  console.log('original greeting')
}

api = {
  hello: hello,
  greeting: greeting
}

describe("jasmine spies on object", function() {
  it("mocks the api.greeting()", function() {
    spyOn(api, "greeting").and.callFake(function() {
      console.log("stubbed `api.greeting()`")
    });
    api.hello();
    expect(api.greeting).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean? `spyOn(api, "greeting")` is essentially saying `api.greeting()`?.  `hello()` calls the global function `greeting()`.  There is no instance called `api` within the `app.js`

Comment: @AAli yes it explicitly says `api.greeting()` - but `api.greeting` is different than `greeting()` - look into tests that proof it